# regular expression to split formatted string into associative array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I have a string that looks like:

```
KEY1,"Value"KEY2,"Value"Key3,"Value"
```

This string will always vary in the number of keys/values i need an associative array:

```
array (
    'KEY1' => 'Value',
    'KEY2' => 'Value',
    'KEY3' => 'Value'
);
```

of the data contained in the string, a regular expression would be best I suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your values don't contain a `"` in them you can do:

```
$str    = 'KEY1,"Value1"KEY2,"Value2"Key3,"Value3"';
$pieces = preg_split('/(?<=[^,]")/',$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$result = array();

foreach($pieces as $piece) {
        list($k,$v) = explode(",",trim$piece);
        $result[$k] = trim($v,'"');
}
```

[**See it in action!**](http://www.ideone.com/V8IlA)

Answer (score 1):

```
php> $str = 'KEY1,"Value"KEY2,"Value"Key3,"Value"';

php> $hash = array();

php> preg_match_all("/(.*?),\"(.*?)\"/", $str, $m);

php> foreach($m[1] as $index => $key) {
 ... $hash[$key] = $m[2][$index];
 ... }

php> var_dump($hash);
array(3) {
  ["KEY1"]=>
  string(5) "Value"
  ["KEY2"]=>
  string(5) "Value"
  ["Key3"]=>
  string(5) "Value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key changes between values then you'll need preg_split().  If the key is always the same then explode() should be more than adequate.

Comment: Explode won't work, I will need a regular expression to find what comes before the , as the key and what is inside the "" as the value. I am just no good with regex.